# Can't connect to openvpn on ubuntu but exact same config works on windows and mac

Tags: networking, 20.04, vpn, openvpn

I've been trying to make openvpn client work on ubuntu 20.04 but could not.
This is the config I'm using on a mac, windows and my ubuntu machine:

```
client
dev tap0
proto tcp
dev-node MY-VPN //only on windows
remote my.server.ip 12974
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert cert.crt
key key.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 6
```

It doesn't connect only on ubuntu.
and here are the open vpn logs from ubuntu machine:

```
 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Sep  5 2019
 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
 LZO compression initializing
 Control Channel MTU parms [ L:1656 D:1210 EF:40 EB:0 ET:0 EL:3 ]
 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1656 D:1450 EF:124 EB:412 ET:32 EL:3 ]
 Local Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1592,tun-mtu 1532,proto TCPv4_CLIENT,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-client'
 Expected Remote Options String (VER=V4): 'V4,dev-type tap,link-mtu 1592,tun-mtu 1532,proto TCPv4_SERVER,comp-lzo,cipher AES-128-CBC,auth SHA1,keysize 128,key-method 2,tls-server'
 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974
 Socket Buffers: R=[131072->131072] S=[16384->16384]
 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974 [nonblock]
 TCP connection established with [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974
 TCP_CLIENT link local: (not bound)
 TCP_CLIENT link remote: [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974
 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974, sid=f683407c c4d6b642
 VERIFY OK: depth=1, C=TW, ST=TW, L=Taipei, O=netgear, OU=netgear, CN=netgear, emailAddress=mail@netgear.com
 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=TW, ST=TW, O=netgear, OU=netgear, CN=netgear, emailAddress=mail@netgear.com
Control Channel: TLSv1, cipher SSLv3 DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA, 1024 bit RSA
[netgear] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974
 Key [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974 [0] not initialized (yet), dropping packet.
 Key [AF_INET]my.server.ip:12974 [0] not initialized (yet), dropping packet.
 SENT CONTROL [netgear]: 'PUSH_REQUEST' (status=1)
 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REPLY,route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0,route-delay 5,redirect-gateway def1,route-gateway dhcp,ping 10,ping-restart 120'
 OPTIONS IMPORT: timers and/or timeouts modified
 OPTIONS IMPORT: route options modified
 OPTIONS IMPORT: route-related options modified
 Data Channel MTU parms [ L:1592 D:1450 EF:60 EB:412 ET:32 EL:3 ]
 Outgoing Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
 Outgoing Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
 Incoming Data Channel: Cipher 'AES-128-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
 Incoming Data Channel: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
 ROUTE_GATEWAY 192.168.2.1/255.255.255.0 IFACE=eno1 HWADDR=70:85:c2:ba:96:d8
 OpenVPN ROUTE: OpenVPN needs a gateway parameter for a --route option and no default was specified by either --route-gateway or --ifconfig options
 OpenVPN ROUTE: failed to parse/resolve route for host/network: 192.168.1.0
 TUN/TAP device tap1 opened
 TUN/TAP TX queue length set to 100
NOTE: unable to redirect default gateway -- VPN gateway parameter (--route-gateway or --ifconfig) is missing
Initialization Sequence Completed
```

It looks like dhcp server address is not updated and routes are not added but I don't really now how to deal with that.

When connecting with the same config on mac via Tunnelblick it looks like it's running it's own up script

```
*Tunnelblick: Start of output from client.up.tunnelblick.sh
*Tunnelblick: WARNING: Tap connection using DHCP but 'Set DNS after routes are set' is not set in Tunnelblick's Advanced settings window (script_type = 'up')
*Tunnelblick: Did 'ipconfig set "tap0" DHCP'
*Tunnelblick: Configuring tap DNS via DHCP asynchronously
*Tunnelblick: End of output from client.up.tunnelblick.sh
```

after which dhcp address is updated and routes are added, vpn connects, my ip address changes and can access both vpn-lan and internet.

I've tried using both NetworkManager and running openvpn from cli but that doesn't seem to change much.
How should I configure my os / client script / do anything else to be able to connect from my linux machine?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue where my `.ovpn` config was working on mac (tunnelblick), but not when I tried to use it on Ubuntu / Manjaro. Only thing I found online was this question and with no responses. Nonetheless, the error I kept getting was:

`Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in [PUSH-OPTIONS]:4: block-outside-dns (2.6.0)`

Simply adding `sudo` at the beginning of the command `openvpn {ovpn_file_name}.ovpn` resolved the issue for me!

(The final command would look like `sudo openvpn {ovpn_file_name}.ovpn`)